# Getting meaningful results from pandas.describe()

Tags: python, pandas

I called describe on one column of a dataframe and ended up with the following output,

```
count    1.048575e+06
mean     8.232821e+01
std      2.859016e+02
min      0.000000e+00
25%      3.000000e+00
50%      1.400000e+01
75%      6.000000e+01
max      8.599700e+04
```

What parameter do I pass to get meaningful integer values. What I mean is when I check the SQL count its about 43 million. All the other values are also different.Can someone help me understand what this conversion means and how do I get float rounded to 2 decimal places. I'm new to Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `round()` and pass the number of decimals you want as argument

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# importing numpy as np 
import numpy as np 

# setting the seed to create the dataframe 
np.random.seed(25) 

# Creating a 5 * 4 dataframe  
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([5, 4]), columns =["A", "B", "C", "D"]) 
# rounding describe
df.describe().round(2)
```

```
    A   B   C   D
count   5.00    5.00    5.00    5.00
mean    0.52    0.47    0.38    0.42
std 0.21    0.23    0.19    0.29
min 0.33    0.12    0.16    0.11
25% 0.41    0.37    0.28    0.19
50% 0.45    0.58    0.37    0.44
75% 0.56    0.59    0.40    0.52
max 0.87    0.70    0.68    0.84
```

[DOCS](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to control the output of pandas, either by controlling it or by using apply.

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.5f' % x)

df['X'].describe().apply("{0:.5f}".format)
```